# How to make this validation logic better?

Tags: c#, .net, validation, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api2

I have a section of code in my validation layer like ----

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.CreditCard) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Billing))
            {
                failures.Add(new FailedValidation(
                        "Billing",
                        "Billing definition incorrect."));
            }  


if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.CreditCard) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Billing))
{
   failures.Add(new FailedValidation(
       "Billing",
        "Billing definition incorrect."));
}
```

The requirement being at least one of `model.Billing` or `model.CreditCard` should be provided. Both cannot be provided.

Now, I have a third new  attribute to be validated - `model.DebitCard` - and the validation logic gets messier as I have to provide for combinations.

At least one should be provided AND only One of them should be provided else validation fails.

How to write this logic in a scalable and efficient manner so that if there is a fourth attribute tomorrow it can also be factored in easily ?

Comment: This may be a good case for a flags enum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could group the fields together and check them to make sure only one is non-null.

Perhaps this would work for you:

```
var fields = new List<string> { model.CreditCard, model.Billing };

if (fields.Count(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)) != 1)
    failures.Add(new FailedValidation("Billing", "Billing definition incorrect."));
```

Comment: If there are 3 fields, Billing is empty and two other filled - message "Billing incorrect" doesn't make much sense (if not completely misleading).

Comment: @GrantWinney - Spot On!  Yes that is correct - messaging is generic at least for now and the above suffices for the Billing process.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered xoring statuses?

```
bool isValid = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.CreditCard) ^ !string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Billing);
if (!isValid)
{
            failures.Add(new FailedValidation(
                    "Billing",
                    "Billing definition incorrect."));
 }
```